# unknown address transaction

Tags: address

I received a transaction with tz (second time) to my KT address., but my KT address is not delegated to this tz. & tz not baker.
  what it could be for an address that sends out small amounts. he has 5971 outgoing transactions.
I noticed that transactions occur once a minute. and go in descending amount

[tzscan tz address](https://href.li/?https://tzscan.io/tz1TDSxFVDJhi2kttgM45PmhkpWRzfhqAozy)

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic... It seems to me that the question is about the behavior of some people or systems, and not really about Tezos.

Comment: it could just be blockchain spam.
Of course I can delete the question.